# Is it OK to be indifferent or inactive when another is being harmed?

Tags: ethics

Is there any word for this type of behavior?

Is it "OK" for a person to stand by while another is harassed or assaulted?

Is it "OK" for a person to have multiple homes and others homeless?

Is it "OK" for a person to have access to thousands of tons of food for years and another starves?

Is it "OK" for a person to have unlimited leisure and another an indentured slave?

I know there is the bystander effect or shock because of a unusual situation where they don't react or respond because of that but I'm talking about those that are aware but indifferent.

Comment: "Callous indifference" is possibly a relevant idea here.... Is there any chance you could share a little more about what made this an interesting or important question in your study of philosophy?

Comment: You also asked https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/is-there-a-name-for-the-ethical-and-unethical-response-that-arises-from-the-juxt which is a near duplicate of this question

Comment: @JosephWeissman One example that lead to this question is that, suspending all the different news, let's say the current president / congress helps Texas and Florida but then suspends help to Puerto Rico. There is the idea of intentional action that leads to someones death (1st degree), then unintentional actions that lead to death (2nd degree) there is there neglectful actions (3rd, 4th, 5th) degree? If the pres doesn't help and pretend he has all power to and that results in deaths what is that?

Comment: @barrycarter I asked that but the answer I received was more related to the name of action of helping someone (I did not receive any answers about when someone doesn't help someone). Since I'm still trying to figure out more about this idea I've written this question.

Comment: As far as the terminological question goes, you might be wondering whether it's 'permissible' to stand by while another is assaulted, &c.

Answer (score 1):

Normally these types of indifferences are inadmissible.

One issue you mentioned in your question can't be solved by a single person alone if he has no power to do that. Did you notice that?

> Is it "OK" for a person to stand by while another is harassed or
>   assaulted?

Most people don't interfere in the quarrel among drunkards.

When a person has a great aim to accomplish in his life (e.g. to save the lives of so many people), sometimes he will ignore some issues.

Sometimes the harassment may be the reaction of an action.

The person may not be willing to react due to his bad condition (e.g.: very weak due to some illness).

Sometimes, if the person responsible to solve the problem is there we usually do not react quickly.

> Is it "OK" for a person to have multiple homes and others homeless?
>
> Is it "OK" for a person to have access to thousands of tons of food
>   for years and another starves?

The persons who destroy the homes, food etc without allowing anybody to use it, are certainly traitors.

> Is it "OK" for a person to have unlimited leisure and another an
>   indentured slave?

The authority to stop such issues are also responsible for these.  Then whose behavior would you blame/name first?

Here we can see at least three persons:

1. the person who is responsible to stop such activity
2. the person who enjoys unlimited leisure
3. the indentured slave

But we usually consider two persons only and name his/her behavior.

When there are more than two persons and when the reference also changes, the name of his/her behavior also changes.

You may try to name the 2nd person's behavior more precisely without considering the 1st person and considering the 1st person. Are they the same?

[This test is applicable also to the two questions given above.]

> Is there any word for this type of behavior?

Here a one-word won't suit everywhere.  We need to name such behavior according to the situations.

The persons in your questions may be rude, introverted, selfish, thoughtless, inconsiderate, domineering etc.

The following link may help you to clear one of your doubts. Sometimes you can connect it to other doubts also.

http://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/35

[You are searching for a suitable word.  This site deals/analyzes ideas very deeply.  So I don't think this site can suggest a suitable word considering different situations.  IMHO you should migrate to a suitable site.]